# Telegram PHP inline_keyboard

Tags: php, keyboard, inline, telegram

I'm trying to create a bot which send an inline_keyboard when in receive the text "/start", the problem is that i can't see the response when i use this function to send the keyboard

```
function sendKeyboard($chat_id, $text) {
$keyboard = ['inline_keyboard' => [                 
                ['text':'Yes'],              
                ['text':'No']            
            ],
   'resize_keyboard' => true,           
   'one_time_keyboard' => true,      
   'selective' => true          
];
$keyboard = json_encode($keyboard);
$url = $GLOBALS[website] . "/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&    
reply_markup=".$keyboard."&text=".urlencode($text);
file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Can somebody understand how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Inline Keyboard buttons is **array of array of Button**, and `resize_keyboard`, `one_time_keyboard` and `selective` is not for inline keyboard, it's parameters for [Reply Keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup).

Your code only have **array of Button**, and Button only have `text` field, it need to add `callback_data` or `url`, or you will get error.

You have better to see [reference](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) about details.

Comment: This code '{"inline_keyboard":[{"text":"test","callback_data":"test"}]]}' it's not working

Comment: @ClaudioStevanato you lost one `[`

Comment: $keyboard = '{"inline_keyboard":
                [
                    [{"text":"test","callback_data":"test"}]
                ]
                }'; not working as before

Comment: Well i simpy can't see the inline keyboard, i can't see a log or something since every part of code is inside the php file

Answer (score 0):

```
  function robot($method,$datas=[]){
  $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".API_KEY."/".$method;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$datas);
  $res = curl_exec($ch);
  if(curl_error($ch)){
      var_dump(curl_error($ch));
  }else{
      return json_decode($res);
  }
}
```

---

```
robot('sendmessage', [
    "chat_id" => $chat_id,
    'message_id'=>$messageid,
    "text" => "* buttonwith out link *
    ",
    'reply_markup' => json_encode([
        "one_time_keyboard" => true,
        'inline_keyboard'=> [
             [
['text' => "button 1", 'callback_data' => "buttoncode-39500"]
]
]
])
]);
```